# UNIX/vim - Verify syntax error

Tags: unix, vim, editor, vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

How can I verify if my code on vim (Unix) has syntax errors?
Is there any command to test the code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin which checks your code.

The one I use, and I'm not alone, is syntactic: https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic

This works for a tons of different languages and even has multiple "lint" engines to choose from for each language. For instance, I use python and can configure syntactic to use one of the following checkers: flake8, pyflakes, pylint and the native python checker. And, yes, it checks vim script as well.

If you can't use any plugins AND only want to debug your vim-scripts, then your best bet is to use vim's own debugger (help debug-scripts).  To use this mode:

> 1. Start vim in debug mode:  `vim -D my_broken_script.vim`
> 2. use `:debug` to switch into debug mode.
> 3. use Ex commands to inspect local variables, `echo idx`, or global ones: `echo g:idx`, where idx is the var.
> 4. set breakpoints with `:breakadd` on either functions or files. And delete them with `:breakdel`
> 5. Use profile to investigate performance issues (help :profile): `:profile start func` and `:profile stop`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'll have an exam on a vim code so I cannot use any plugins. I was hoping there was a way to verify my code using vim editor.

Comment: Have you used vim -D, as in Debugging? That might work for you? If that works for you, I'll update my answer and provide more details.

Comment: And if I execute the files? Could be a solution, right?
But, how can I execute a C code on vim? Thank you!

Comment: @Uzareth, that's a separate question! But, yes, one can compile C code in vim and review compiler errors : read the help on :make and :copen.